# Quartz Shutdown hook

Tags: servlets, quartz-scheduler

We have implemented quartz API to schedule jobs.And we are triggering these jobs using an UI using Servlets. Below is the flow.
 HTML UI --> Job Triggering request goes to servlet --> Servlet invokes the Quartz API to schedule the job.

Here the question is, We want to notify(mail notiifcation) the user in below cases
1.Application goes down.
2.Quartz job shutsdown(because of some issue)

Is there any possibility to get  hook of above mentioned cases to notify the user?

Thanks,
Satyendra

Answer (score 0):

Quartz itself does not provide any monitoring functionality. So you have two options:

1. You will implement it yourself. In that case you should check the Quartz API javadoc. You are especially interested in the [JobListener](http://javadox.com/org.quartz-scheduler/quartz/2.2.1/org/quartz/JobListener.html) and [SchedulerListener](http://javadox.com/org.quartz-scheduler/quartz/2.2.1/org/quartz/SchedulerListener.html) APIs to monitor job executions and scheduler status changes respectively.
2. You can use and existing 3rd party solutions such as [JWatch](https://code.google.com/p/jwatch/), or [QuartzDesk](http://www.quartzdesk.com) (I am biased here).